# How to convert string to char?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a problem to output a string. Can you help me?

In the following, `const char * i` and `const char ** o` are given.

The statement,  "`*o = temp`" produces an error, saying that "`std::string`" and "`const char *`" do not fit. What is the problem?

```
int mytask(const char * i, const char ** o)
{
    std::string temp = std::string("mytask:") + i;

    *o = temp; //How to modify?

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Use [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to copy the contents of `temp` in to `*o`? And why are you passing a `char **`? Does `mytask` need to allocate memory for the the string as well?

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us what you were trying to do. It looks like you're trying to make `o` point into an object that will no longer exist when you return.

Comment: Why is it `const char **o`? You are trying to modify it in function then why `const`?

Comment: @Johnsyweb Concatenate..?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are trying to assign a local char pointer and use it in calling function, where it have already been destroyed. So instead you should do this. Assuming memory is allocated for o:

```
strcpy(*o,temp.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

`*o=temp`  means you are making the o point to a pointer that points to a std::string however o is a pointer that points to a char (or sequence of chars). This is not allowed. The other way around works: `temp=*o` because the std::string object defines what happens when you assign a char* to it (copy the null terminated string into the object). If you absolutely must copy from temp into the char* pointed to by o*. use  [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) and [std::string.c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)
`strcpy(*o,temp.c_str())`

Answer (score 1):

In C++, it's unusual to pass raw pointers around in this manner.

Returning `0` doesn't achieve much either.

I'd expect to see something like this:

```
std::string mytask(std::string const& i)
{
    return "mytask:" + i;
}

int main()
{
    std::string const number { '1' };
    std::string const ret { mytask(number) };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement
    strcpy(*o,temp.c_str());
didn't work. I resolved this problem by
    *o = temp.c_srt();
instead. Thanks all anyway.